# Parsing JSON with GoLang in AWS Lamda

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, go

As part of an application we are building, one of the process steps is an AWS Lamda that captures a post request does some work with it, and then moves one. It has an API Gateway Request as a trigger and the body of this request would be a JSON String. I am having trouble parsing the JSON String to GoLang Object. Here is what I have:

The function that catches request:

```
func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, event events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {

  log.Print(fmt.Sprintf("body:[%s] ", event.Body))

  parseResponseStringToTypedObject(event.Body)

  return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
     StatusCode: http.StatusOK,
     Body:       "OK",
  },  nil
}
```

Then the `parseResponseStringToTypedObject` function :

```
func parseResponseStringToTypedObject(responseString string) {

  b := []byte(responseString)
  var resp SimpleType
  err := json.Unmarshal(b, &resp)

  if err == nil {
      log.Print(fmt.Sprintf("Account Name: [%s]", resp.accountName))
  } else {
      log.Print(fmt.Sprintf("Could not unmarshall JSON string: [%s]", err.Error()))
  }
}
```

Here is the `SimpleType` struct:

```
type SimpleType struct {
  accountName string `json:accountName`
  amount      int    `json:amount`
}
```

I then, as a test, posted this JSON Body via Postman:
[image]

I opened up the CloudWatch Logs (where my lamda logs to) and see that the body is present in the `event.Body` property, and then logging out a field in the unmarshalled object (resp.accountName) I note that the field is blank. Why is this? Here is log output for the request:

[image]

Comment: You misplaced the `if` and `else` branches. Condition is `if err != nil `, and the error branch is on the `else`. Meaning when your `err` is `nil`, the `else` branch is executed and you call `err.Error()` which causes your runtime panic.

Comment: Aah I see, that fixed the error being thrown, thanks! Now I get the object Unmarshalled, but the values are blank - Will update the Question.

Comment: What does `SimpleType` look like? The blank values could have everything to do with how the tags are defined there

Comment: Sorry, I thought I did post it there, updated the post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `SimpleType` struct needs 2 things here...

1) The properties need to be "public" or "exported". Meaning they need to start with an upper cased character.

*AND*

2) The properties need proper tags for the serialization and de serialization of JSON. e.g. each JSON tag surrounded by `"`

```golang
type SimpleType struct {
  AccountName string `json:"accountName"`
  Amount int `json:"amount"`
}
```

Hope this helps!